# bulk data insert in mysql - wallet program

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, database-design

I have a mysql table structure by the following image link. I need to update every user account with some amount with every purchase happen by the portal. If I have >100k customers I need to update a different amount for every user.I know 100k query executions would be slow. Is there any alternative solution?

[image: PHP MYADMIN Image link here]

Comment: MySQL will support inserting multiple rows from one insert statement. This is quite efficient when inserting hundreds or even a few thousand rows at once.

Comment: Do you need to update every user at once, or whenever a user makes a purchase their row needs to be updated?

Comment: need to insert a new row by the following: closing = existing balance,opening = updated balance,opposition = amount for this transaction

Comment: "Update" is not a "bulk data insert" -- which are you talking about?  There are different solutions for them.

Comment: At my case our project has some internal calculation.every user account has added by 10 - 100 INR per day once by running some calculation.